# android.os.Build returns "null"

Tags: java, android, maven, automated-tests

I'm currently using Appium and Maven as parts of my automated testing framework. In the past, I've been able to set the device name in the capabilities by grabbing an Android device's serial number by using

```
device = android.os.Build.ID
```

**device** is obviously declared as a String.

The **pom.xml** originally included the following:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I then changed the version tag to **4.1.1.4**. Ever since,  **device** will always return null. Reverting back to an older version unfortunately does not resolve my issue. Please assist.

edit: I forgot to add "ID" to the end of device = android.os.Build.

Comment: `android.os.Build` is a class -- are you meaning to use `android.os.Build.DEVICE` instead?

Comment: @kcoppock I forgot to add "ID". It needs to say **android.os.Build.ID**

Also, I tried `android.os.Build.DEVICE` and it still returned null.